# CS50 Pset7 Movies - 13.sql

Tags: cs50

I am on the last step for this problem set, and am having a problem getting the names of people who starred in a movie in which Kevin Bacon also starred.  I have put this code together, and it is producing only one name right now, Steve Guttenberg.  Based on the logic that I have in my code (I will include notes) it should give me all of the names (yes, I know Kevin Bacon himself should not be in this list ultimately, but I am trying to solve one problem at a time).

```
SELECT name  --Get name where the id is equal to the id in stars in the next step
FROM people
WHERE id = (
    SELECT person_id  --Get all the star's ids who are in the movies in which Kevin Bacon starred in
    FROM stars
    WHERE stars.movie_id = (
            SELECT movie_id  --Get all movie ids where Kevin Bacon starred in
            FROM stars
            Where stars.person_id = (
                SELECT id       --Get Kevin Bacon's ID
                FROM people
                WHERE people.name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958)
                            )
            )
```

I am unsure where the logic is breaking in my code.  Has anyone else had similar issues?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `SELECT movie_id  --Get all movie ids` essentially returns a *list* of the movies in which KB starred. Here `WHERE stars.movie_id = (` it needs to select all `movie_id` that are IN that "list".

Ditto here `WHERE id = (` it needs to select all the `id`  that are IN the `person_id` "list".

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping, I understood what you said and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow a workaround and nest the expressions WHERE ... IN. So, you first separate the movie ids where Kevin Bacon, who was born in 1958, starred. This way, you will have access to the person ids that starred in the movie with Kevin.

Then, using the people table, you can pull out all the names except Kevin Bacon's. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT name from people WHERE
id IN (SELECT person_id FROM stars WHERE
movie_id IN (SELECT movie_id FROM stars INNER JOIN people on stars.person_id = people.id
WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958)) AND name != "Kevin Bacon";
```